# I want to return a default value as NULL for some condition in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am running the below SQL query in SQL Server where I need to return a default value as ’NULL’ when a condition is not met. The result should be displayed as NULL  for some records which doesn’t meet the criteria but I am getting a blank space in-place of NULL.Can someone please help?

There are few rows in my table which doesn’t meet the criteria so I should be seeing NULL in my result.

```
SELECT NAME,
CASE 
     WHEN AGE >=18 AND SEX='M' THEN 'Adult Male' 
     WHEN AGE>18 AND SEX='M' 'Non-Adult Male'
     WHEN AGE >=18  AND SEX='F' THEN 'Adult Female'
     WHEN AGE<18 AND TITLE='F' THEN 'Non-Adult Female'
     ELSE NULL
END AS AGE_SEX,
ADDRESS, 
SALARY
FROM PERSONALS;
```

Comment: Can you please edit out the smart quotes? Those should be normal single quotes.

Comment: well, you have messed up your conditions, you have `SEX = 'F'` or `SEX = 'M'` for some, but `TITLE = 'F'` for another. Also, `AGE >= 18` for `Adult`, but also `AGE > 18` for `Non Adult`

Comment: Keep in mind that a true null value will be displayed as a blank value, depending on what is displaying it.  If you want a `NULL` *string*, then use `'NULL'`, with single quotes.

Answer (score 2):

Your logic is not correct.  Here is a way to fix it, taking into account that `case` statements cascade -- that is, the logic chooses the first match:

```
SELECT NAME,
       (CASE WHEN AGE >= 18 AND SEX = 'M' THEN 'Adult Male'
             WHEN AGE < 18 AND SEX = 'M' THEN 'Non-Adult Male'
             WHEN AGE >= 18 AND SEX = 'F' THEN 'Adult Female'
             WHEN AGE < 18 AND SEX = 'F' THEN 'Non-Adult Female'
        END) AS AGE_SEX
```

Note:  The `ELSE NULL` is redundant, because the `CASE` returns `NULL` when no conditions match.

Comment: Though this is most likely correct, it would be better if the conditions are explicit: `WHEN AGE < 18 AND SEX = 'M' THEN 'Non-Adult Male'`. In your answer, if the `AGE` IS NULL and `SEX = 'M'`, then it will return `'Non-Adult Male'` instead of `NULL` as op's question

Comment: However it is best practice to be explicit with the logic

Comment: @Lamak . . . That is a good point, which is why I changed it.  I don't agree that being explicit is necessarily a best practice, even if it is the right thing to do in this case.

Comment: I saw the change and I think it's good now. I was talking about this case in particular, and didn't say anything about good practices